# Trouble building Shapefile in Geotools

Tags: java, shapefile, geotools

I have a project where I want to load in a given shapefile, and pick out polygons above a certain size before writing the results to a new shapefile. Maybe not the most efficient, but I've got code that successfully does all of that, right up to the point where it is supposed to write the shapefile. I get no errors, but the resulting shapefile has no usable data in it. I've followed as many tutorials as possible, but still I'm coming up blank.

The first bit of code is where I read in a shapefile, pickout the polygons I want, and put then into a feature collection. This part seems to work fine as far as I can tell.

```
public class ShapefileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, FactoryException, MismatchedDimensionException, TransformException, SchemaException {

        File oldShp = new File("Old.shp"); 
        File newShp = new File("New.shp"); 

        //Get data from the original ShapeFile
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("url", oldShp.toURI().toURL());
        //Connect to the dataStore
        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
        //Get the typeName from the dataStore
        String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

        //Get the FeatureSource from the dataStore
        FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

        SimpleFeatureCollection collection = (SimpleFeatureCollection) source.getFeatures(); //Get all of the features - no filter        

        //Start creating the new Shapefile
        final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = createFeatureType(); //Calls a method that builds the feature type - tested and works.
        DefaultFeatureCollection newCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection();  //To hold my new collection

        try (FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> features = collection.features()) {
            while (features.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature feature = features.next();  //Get next feature
                SimpleFeatureBuilder fb = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);  //Create a new SimpleFeature based on the original
                Integer level = (Integer) feature.getAttribute(1); //Get the level for this feature
                MultiPolygon multiPoly = (MultiPolygon) feature.getDefaultGeometry(); //Get the  geometry collection

                //First count how many new polygons we will have
                int numNewPoly = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < multiPoly.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
                    double area = getArea(multiPoly.getGeometryN(i));
                    if (area > 20200) {
                        numNewPoly++;
                    }
                }

                //Now build an array of the larger polygons
                Polygon[] polys = new Polygon[numNewPoly];  //Array of new geometies

                int iPoly = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < multiPoly.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
                    double area = getArea(multiPoly.getGeometryN(i));
                    if (area > 20200) {  //Write the new data
                        polys[iPoly] = (Polygon) multiPoly.getGeometryN(i);
                        iPoly++;
                    }
                }

                GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();     //Create a geometry factory           
                MultiPolygon mp = new MultiPolygon(polys, gf);  //Create the MultiPolygonyy
                fb.add(mp); //Add the geometry collection to the feature builder
                fb.add(level);
                fb.add("dBA");

                SimpleFeature newFeature = SimpleFeatureBuilder.build( TYPE, new Object[]{mp, level,"dBA"}, null );
                newCollection.add(newFeature); //Add it to the collection
            }
```

At this point I have a collection that looks right - it has the correct bounds and everything. The next bit if code is where I put it into a new Shapefile.

```
            //Time to put together the new Shapefile                
            Map<String, Serializable> newMap = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
            newMap.put("url", newShp.toURI().toURL());
            newMap.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

            DataStore newDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(newMap);
            newDataStore.createSchema(TYPE);
            String newTypeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

            SimpleFeatureStore fs = (SimpleFeatureStore) newDataStore.getFeatureSource(newTypeName);            

            Transaction t = new DefaultTransaction("add");    

            fs.setTransaction(t);
            fs.addFeatures(newCollection);

            t.commit();
            ReferencedEnvelope env = fs.getBounds();

        }

    }
```

I put in the very last code to check the bounds of the FeatureStore fs, and it comes back null. Obviously, loading the newly created shapefile (which DOES get created and is ab out the right size), nothing shows up.

Answer (score 3):

The solution actually had nothing to do with the code I posted - it had everything to do with my FeatureType definition. I did not include the "the_geom" to my polygon feature type, so nothing was getting written to the file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing the step to finalize/close the file.  Try adding this after the the `t.commit` line.

```
fs.close();
```

As an expedient alternative, you might try out the Shapefile dumper utility mentioned in the Shapefile DataStores [docs](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html#dumping-almost-anything-into-a-shapefile).  Using that may simplify your second code block into two or three lines.

Comment: That does not fix the fact that the feature bounds are null. The feature itself is not created properly. Closing the transaction did not fix that problem. And I will look into the Shapefile DataStore in more detail, thanks!

Comment: I've tried even simpler code that just makes a MultiPolygon with a hole, and get the same problem...I am obviously missing something in how to create the feature...